# After Initial GUI AppJar Python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

I am using AppJar with Python 3.6 and I am trying to figure out how you get past your initial window. i have a basic login screen and the script is.

```
from appJar import gui
app = gui("Login Window", '1920x1080')
app.setFont(20
app.addLabel("title", 'Enter Title Here')
app.setLabelBg("title", 'red')
app.addLabelEntry("Username")
app.addLabelSecretEntry("Password ")
def press(button):
    if button == "Cancel":
        app.stop()
else:
    user = app.getEntry("Username")
    pwd = app.getEntry("Password")
    print("User:", user,"Password:", pwd)

app.addButtons(["Submit", "Cancel"],press)
app.go()
```

I would like to open another interface when you press the submit button, how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a read of this: http://appjar.info/pythonSubWindows/

Make your login window a **subWindow**

Then start appJar, showing the **subWindow**

When the user has correctly logged in, hide the **subWindow** and show the main GUI:

```
def login(btn):
    app.hideSubWindow("Login")
    app.show()

app.startSubWindow("Login")
app.addLabel("l2", "Login Window")
app.addButton("SUBMIT", login)
app.stopSubWindow()

app.go(startWindow="Login")
```